# magento custom function to be used in all product detail pages

Tags: product, product-list

i want to make a custom function to be used for product listing pages , where to create the function ??? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague. You should describe what you need to achieve.
Based on the little things I understood from your question I would say that you should create a module with a helper and put your function in that helper:

Something like this:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function doSomething($arg1, $arg2, ...) {
        //dragons here
    }
}
```

If you declare your helpers in `config.xml` like this

```
<helpers>
     <[namespace]_[module]>
        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Helper</class>
     </[namespace]_[module]>
</helpers>
```

You should be able to use it anywhere like this:

```
Mage::helper('[namespace]_[module]')->doSomething($arg1, $arg2, ...)
```

But if you plan to edit any template to use your method you should wrap the usage of your method in an `if`statement that checks if the module is enabled.

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('[Namespace]_[Module]')) : ?>
    Mage::helper('[namespace]_[module]')->doSomething($arg1, $arg2, ...);
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: ok fine if i create function there will i be able to call that on product listing page or define any scope that i may be able to call that function of product detail page . new to magento so no idea ?.

Comment: Yes...you need to modify the templates that you need.

Comment: can u tell way to call function in product detail page created via above module ?

Comment: The template that renders the product page is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`. Use that one to add your modifications. I already explained what you need to do, in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement your own `layout.xml` file (google for it) and use the layout handle `catalog_prodct_view` to insert your block to all product detail pages.